# R number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length / results however correct

Tags: r, for-loop, warnings

I know there have been already some threads on this, however going through those I was not able to figure out what the problem might be - please forgive me for that..

I am trying to run the code

```
  for (i in 1:a){
    matrix$new_column[i]<-which(matrix[i,1:b-1]==matrix$col_b[i])
  }
```

What I am attempting is:
For the *matrix* of *a* lines and *b* columns, in each line´s columns *2* to *b-1*, find the one that contains the same value as the one in column *b* (there is always such a value) and write the according column number into the *new_column*

My Code keeps throwing the error

> Warning in matrix$new_column[i] <- which(matrix[i,  :   number of
>   items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

However, the result is completely correct. I have tried

- creating the *new_column* filled with 0s first
- changing the end indices from *a* to *a-1* or *a+1*

As said, the outcome is correct, however I feel I should not be getting the warning message if I did everything correctly, so I´m really grateful for any advice on how to fix this.

Finally, don´t ask me why I chose 1:b-1 when I wanted to go from 2 to b-1, I just saw that when I would use 2:b-1, it would acutally begin in column 3..

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning.

Comment: yes, sorry, my bad. Still, should it not throw warnings if I did it correctly?

Comment: It means the length of your new vector is not the same length as the one which produced it.  So something may be incorrect, even though the results look correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`which()` can return a vector if there are multiple matches.  For example:

```
which((1:12)%%2 == 0) # which are even?
```

Is `matrix$col_b[i]` unique? The results may still look correct.  Notice what happens in this case:

```
x <- 1:2
x[1] <- 3:4
x
```

Also, `1:b-1` does not give you the numbers from `1` to `b - 1` but the number from `1` to `b`, all minus `1`:

```
b <- 10
1:b-1
```

You need parentheses to force the subtraction first: `1:(b - 1)`.

Comment: OK, I did not foresee the case that I might have two equal values. Fixed it and the error went away - Thanks! As for the missing parenthesis, thanks for that too :)

Answer (score 0):

or try this if you want to create five vectors of Y's.

```
set.seed(101)
    lambda_j <- rgamma(1000,1,1)

    Y <- matrix(NA, nrow=1000, ncol=5)
for (j in 1:ncol(Y)) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(Y)) {
    Y[,j] <- rpois(1000,lambda_j)
  }
}
```