# Prequential Evaluation in R Causing Error Message

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I'm implementing Prequential Evaluation in R using `RMOA`.

This isn't too important for the question, but basically this evaluates  performance of a stream mining classifier by *first testing*  and *then training* the model for every observation in a stream.

I have it largely completed, except I'm encountering this error message when making predictions:

> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I'm using the Iris dataset, and strangely it predicts class labels and trains for the first 50 observations as I would expect. For the remaining 100, however, it produces the above error. The dataset is in its default order :

```
Label        Number

Setosa       50
Versicolor   50
Virginica    50
```

This means that for whatever reason, the model is making predictions on all of the Setosa observations, and then produces this error for the other two class labels. If I randomise the rows I encounter the same problem; as soon a second class label is encountered the error is produced.

I've read similar questions surrounding this error, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099461/r-number-of-items-to-replace-is-not-a-multiple-of-replacement-length-results-h). None of the existing questions seem to address the problem in the context of classification.

Relevant R code:

```
require(RMOA)
require(stream)

#data<-iris[sample(nrow(iris)),] #use this for randomising the iris dataset
df = datastream_dataframe(as.data.frame(iris))

opts<-MOAoptions(model="HoeffdingTree")
tree<-HoeffdingTree(control = opts)
mymodel <- NULL

i<- 1
#Iterate over the stream until the stream is empty
repeat
{
    element <- df$get_points(1)

    #Check to see if stream is empty - not elegant but it works just now
    if(is.null(element$Species)){
        break
    }

    #Prequential evaluation
    tryCatch(
    {
        #First test
        pred <- RMOA:::predict.MOA_trainedmodel(mymodel, element, type="response")
        cat("Tested element ", i, "Pred: ",pred, ". Label: ", element$Species,"\n")

        #Then train
        #If first element in stream, the model is initially trained in the error block below
        if(!i==1){
            mymodel <<- trainMOA(model = mymodel$model, 
                formula = Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
                data = datastream_dataframe(element))
            cat("Trained model using element ", i,"\n")
        }
    },

    error = function(err){
        cat("Error processing element ", i,"\n")
        if(i==1){
            cat("The model was initially untrained.\n")
            mymodel <<- trainMOA(model = tree, Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = datastream_dataframe(element))
        }
        else{
            message(err)
        }
    })#end try-catch block

    i<<- i+ 1
}#end while
```

Note that initially the model is set to `null`. For the first observation, the attempted prediction will produce an error since the model is untrained. This is handled within the `try-catch`. All subsequent observations should be tested before training.

What is wrong with my model that it produces this error?

Comment: Isn't there a "In ... :" that prints before that warning?  That tells you where to look.  Place a call to `browser()` right before the line raising the warning, and examine your objects' lengths.  Also, minimal examples of a problem are more likely to get answers.

Comment: There's no "ln" that prints before. As for minimal, ordinarily I would of cut the excess text but I was trying to avoid potential questions about why the training/testing structure

Comment: The warning you're seeing isn't specific to what you're doing.  It commonly comes up when assumptions about vector lengths prove wrong.  You should go through your code step by step and find out which line raises the warning.  It might be a flaw in a package you're using; in that case, you're best off letting the package maintainer know about the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found the bug originally reported on the [MOA-users Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moa-users/xkDG6p15FIM).

The issue was addressed as a bug in commit `39665f9` by the package author as stated in the [issue I opened on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/jwijffels/RMOA/issues/10).

Installing `RMOA` via CRAN results in version 1.0 which still contains this bug. To avoid, install version 1.1 which is available from the package [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jwijffels/RMOA) or by using the following

```
install_github("jwijffels/RMOA", subdir="RMOA/pkg")
```